# Jquery: find element in var and change text

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following expression is not working: (*neither with* `.text()`)

```
$(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').html(file.name);
```

File.previewElement is a variable = `$(".preview-template").html();`

For `$(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]')`the debugger outputs:

```
Object { 0: <span>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: undefined, selector: "[data-dz-name]" }
```

This is about following Code:

```
<div class="preview-template" style="display: none;">
<div class="body content ig">
    <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
        <h2 class="dz-filename">File: <span data-dz-name></span></h2>

        <img class="dz-thumb" data-dz-thumbnail />
        <div class="dz-progress"></div>
                <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
                Details:
                <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>


        <div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div>
        <div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the entire HTML content as a selector, which is not valid do to. If you want your variable to be a selector change your variable to be `$(".preview-template")`, removing the `.html()` on the end.

---

For having `file.previewElement` as a separate instance variable for your HTML element you can use (as you already found out) [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/). Which will give you a array of nodes that you can manipulate using jQuery:

```
file.previewElement = $.parseHTML($(".preview-template").html());
```

Comment: I do not want to change the content of `$(".preview-template")`. file.previewElement is supossed to be a new instance of the template

Comment: @guest Do you mean you would like your variable to be a separate instance as a string of HTML, and change/search that string only?

Comment: Yes. I just foud the answer myself by using `.parseHTML()`. Im sorry if my question has been a bit misleading in terms of this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code from

```
$(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').html(file.name);
```

to

```
$(".preview-template").find('[data-dz-name]').html(file.name);
```

In case you need to have variable for the element and also for the template then you have to introduce a new variable and update your code like following

```
file.previewElement = $(".preview-template");
file.previewTemplate = file.previewElement.html();
file.previewElement.find('[data-dz-name]').html(file.name);
```

Comment: I do not want to change the content of `$(".preview-template")`. file.previewElement is supossed to be a new instance of the template

Comment: @guest - In that case either you need to add a new variable or can make change like one I have done as per my updated answer

Comment: well how do I add a new variable? because file.templateElement is supposed to be a new one

Comment: @guest - I have updated the answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".preview-template").find('[data-dz-name]').html(file.name);`